# InterfaceError with sqlalchemy and Microsoft Access Driver in Python

Tags: python, ms-access, sqlalchemy, driver, pyodbc

I want to connect to a MS Acces database that is on my host system.
I am using Python 3.7 in jupyter notebook. When I connect to the engine, I get the exception InterfaceError.

My Code:

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection_string = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=./Datenbank1.accdb;'
)
connect_str = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(connection_string)}"
engine = create_engine(connect_str, echo=True)
engine.connect()
```

> InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht
> gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben (0)
> (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at:
> http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)

The data source name was not found and no default driver was specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Can you help me to find the error?
Maybe I am missing the right driver but I don't know how to install it

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what ODBC drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: Ok, I get a list with two drivers ['SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']. How can I add new Microsoft drivers?

Comment: The list indicates that you are running 64-bit Python so you can download the 64-bit Access driver from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

Comment: OK, that works. now I have the following drivers:
['SQL Server',
 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)',
 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)',
 'Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)',
 'Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)']
but now I get another Error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65301510/dbapierror-with-sqlalchemy-and-ms-acces

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, one way to tell if a Python script is running as 32-bit or 64-bit is to check the output from `pyodbc.drivers()`. In 32-bit mode, the list will include the older "Jet" driver …

Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)

… (note: no mention of `*.accdb`) which ships with Windows and is only available as 32-bit.

In this case the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` did not include that driver so we can deduce that the script is running as 64-bit. Therefore the solution is to download the 64-bit version of the newer "ACE" ODBC driver from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

For more details on connecting to Access via pyodbc, see the [pyodbc wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Microsoft-Access).